# Could not find 'ssleay32.dll' error while installing pyopenssl

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pyopenssl

I keep seeing this error constantly and I tried copying the ssleay32.dll to the systems directory and the error still happens .

Could someone please help me how to fix it ?

```
<...>
Collecting pyOpenSSL==0.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info
    creating pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    error: could not find 'ssleay32.dll'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\niyer\desktop\temp\pip-build-zgixxx\pyOpenSSL\
```

Comment: do not post text as a picture

Comment: Sorry , here is the error -

Comment: edit it into your question instead

Answer (score 0):

`0.13.1` is a very old version. The current one (as of this writing) is [`16.1.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL). The code for the message [is not even in the repo anymore](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ssleay32&type=Code). Are you really specifically interested in such an old codebase?

The new version relies on a [statically linked version of `openssl` in its dependency module, `cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-windows), so you don't need to worry about having it elsewhere any longer.